# WPF Get TreeViewItem Parent index

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing, treeview, parent

Is there a way to get the selected item's parent's index in a `TreeView` in WPF?
I can loop through the items and then come with an index of the selected item but getting `TreeViewItem`'s `Paren`'s index seems complicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: @Amine I actually found a solution my self. Thank you for being interested in helping. You can check the code in the answers

Answer (score 0):

Found a great(for my needs) solution. I will share it for future references.

```
private int? GetTreeViewItemParentIndex(TreeViewItem Item)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            foreach (var _item in treeView1.Items)
            {
                if (_item == Item.Parent)
                {
                    return index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            return null;
            //throw new Exception("No parent window detected");
        }

private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewItem SelectedNode = ((TreeViewItem)((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem);
            int? ParentIndex = GetTreeViewItemParentIndex(SelectedNode);
            if (ParentIndex != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ParentIndex.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No parent detected");
            }
    }
```